# How do I add text file and reach it from SharedCode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've a text file and I want to reach it from a shared code project. I want it to work for Android, iOS and Windows Phone. What would be the best approach and where should I put the text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin to reach it: https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

For more information about where to put it and build settings take a look at this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Answer (score 0):

Since a shared project gets compiled into the native project you will need to place it there (copy the file to the Android, iOS & Windows Phone project). Now you have to access it from your shared project by using reflection like this:

```
var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNativeAssembly.FolderYouPutTheFileIn.filename.txt"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

*Do note that the file you just added should be a EmbeddedResource!*

If you want to target multiple platforms you would probably have to change the 'YourNativeAssembly' based on the platform (or name every native assembly the same). To do that see [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/) documentation.